# How do I compress a directory auto use directory name?

Tags: 14.04, tar

I have to assign file name when I use tar

```
tar -zcvf xxx.tar.gz /home/xxx
```

I always use history command , and alter the directory name and tar file name.I would make mistake at sometime to input a exist tar file name, then that file would be cover...

Right click menu of Winrar in windows  have a option 'compress to XXX', can auto create a rar file with the directory name.
How can I achieve this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `.bashrc` file with your editor and add this line:

```
   function tardir() {
        tar -zcvf $1.tar.gz $1
        return $?
   }
   export -f tardir
```

Save `.bashrc` and run this command:

```
  source .bashrc
```

Now you should call your function as command:

```
  tardir XXX
```

You can add more bash code in order to check if tar file already exists or if XXX exists and so on, as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The directory to which you extract your tar file should exist:

```
mkdir foo
tar -xzf bar.tar.gz -C foo
```